# Install Windows service on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, services

I've a Windows Service installer created in Windows 7 using C#. This service will only work on net.pipe not in http. I want this service to be installed in Ubuntu and running.
Could anybody guide me how to to achieve this. If need more information please ask.